# .gdb table creation speed

Tags: shapefile, file-geodatabase, c++, file-geodatabase-api

I'm trying to convert a shapefile containing N single point shapes to a .gdb using the `FileGDBAPI` for `C++` from Esri.

The structure of the shapefile is:

```
   x   |    y     |    date1     |   date2     |  date3    |   ....
---------------------------------------------------------------------
   0   |    0     |     1        |    2        |    3      |   ....
   1   |    0     |     2        |    1        |    0      |   ....
```

and so on where there could be an unknown number N of dates and Z of different points

Right now all I'm doing is creating a new `.gdb` file, creating a table with these fields and populating it with the same data as the shapefile.

This all works. The problem is that it's awfully slow, to convert a `shapefile` with 60k points it takes almost 20 minutes.

Is there something obvious I'm missing or that I could refactor to speed up the process a bit? Right now I'm opening the `.shp`, reading the fields in the `.dbf`, creating a table with those fields, populating it with the various entries in the `.dbf` and closing the table and the `.gdb`

Here is pretty much my code (error checking removed to save space but it's in the real program). Where there are comments I can't write the complete implementation but it does what it says in the comments and it's correct and optimized.

```
std::vector<shapes> shape_list; //Contains the shape points

FileGDBAPI::Geodatabase geodatabase;
error = CreateGeodatabase(L"./test.gdb"), geodatabase);

FileGDBAPI::SpatialReference spatialReference;
spatialReference.SetSpatialReferenceText(prj_string);
error = geodatabase.CreateFeatureDataset(L"\\Spatial_Reference", spatialReference);

std::vector<FileGDBAPI::FieldDef> field_defs;

for (int i = 0; i < dbf_field_number; ++i){
    std::string dbf_field_name = field_name(i); // this gives me the dbf field name at position i

    FileGDBAPI::FieldDef current_dbf_field;
    current_dbf_field.SetName(dbf_field_name);
    current_dbf_field.SetType(FileGDBAPI::fieldTypeDouble);
    current_dbf_field.SetIsNullable(true);
    current_dbf_field.SetAlias(dbf_field_name);
    current_dbf_field.SetGeometryDef(geometryDef);
    field_defs.push_back(current_dbf_field);
}

FileGDBAPI::Table table;
error = geodatabase.CreateTable(L"\\Data", field_defs, L"DEFAULTS", table);

for (int i = 0; i < shape_number; ++i){
    FileGDBAPI::Row row;
    table.CreateRowObject(row);
    
    FileGDBAPI::PointShapeBuffer row_point;
    row_point.Setup(FileGDBAPI::shapePoint);

    FileGDBAPI::Point* point;
    row_point.GetPoint(point);

    point->x = shape_list[i]->getX();
    point->y = shape_list[i]->getY();

    row->SetGeometry(dbf_row_point);

    for (int j = 0; j < dbf_field_number; ++j){
         std::string dbf_field_name = field_name(j);
         double dbf_value = field_value(i, dbf_field_name);

         error = row->SetDouble(dbf_field_name, dbf_value);
    }

    error = table.Insert(row);
}
error = geodatabase.CompactDatabase();
error = CloseGeodatabase(geodatabase);
```

Comment: It's been years since I last played with FileGDB.DLL, but I remember 20 minutes being the million row table threshold on creation. Without code, responses about changes are useless.

Comment: I've added the code I have, error checking is removed to not make it too long and the internal data structures are not present but just take for granted that they work correctly and are optimized (like the one to read the shapes)

Comment: All I have right now is a log of some networked drive access performance tests that indicate that populating 10k random point rows took ~2600 milliseconds on a high-end laptop seven years ago, which would put 60k features at ~16 seconds.  You don't seem to be using `table.SetWriteLock()` and `table.FreeWriteLock()` which means a lock needs to be obtained for each row.  I also question the need for a `CompactDatabase` without any random access edits.

Comment: @Vince in full honesty, I don't understand why `CompactDatabase` is needed either. All I'm basing the code is the (in my opinion severely lacking) `FilaGDBAPI` documentation that just states: _Compact the geodatabase. Recomended after bulk updates_ . In my view adding a whole table with many fields constitutes as "bulk update"

Comment: No, "bulk updates" are UPDATEs (which change the width of existing rows), not INSERTs (which append to the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last FileGDPAPI code I wrote (which loaded 10k random points) had this helper function to populate a table:

```c
std::wstring populateTable(Table& table)
{
    int           j;
    fgdbError     hr;
    Row           row;
    Point        *point;
    PointShapeBuffer  pointGeom;
    short         rndInt    = 0;
    wstring       msg   = L"";
    wstring       rndString = L"a";
static  wstring       array[] = {
                L"a", L"bb", L"ccc", L"dddd", L"eeeee",
                L"f", L"gg", L"hhh", L"iiii", L"jjjjj",
                L"k", L"ll", L"mmm", L"nnnn", L"ooooo",
                L"p", L"qq", L"rrr", L"ssss", L"ttttt",
                L"u", L"vv", L"www", L"xxxx", L"yyyyy",
                L"z", L"bb", L"hhh", L"nnnn", L"ttttt" };

/*
 * .. Load-only mode
 */
    if ((hr = table.SetWriteLock()) != S_OK) {
        ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
        goto bailout;
    }

/*
 * .. Prep
 */
    if ((hr = table.CreateRowObject(row)) != S_OK) {
        ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
        goto bailout;
    }
    if ((hr = pointGeom.Setup(shapePoint)) != S_OK) {
        ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
        goto bailout;
    }
    if ((hr = pointGeom.GetPoint(point)) != S_OK) {
        ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
        goto bailout;
    }

/*
 * .. Insert values
 */
    for (j = 0; j < INSERT_CNT; j++) {

        rndString = array[randomShort(0,STRING_CNT)];
        if ((hr = row.SetString(L"RNDSTRING",rndString)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }

        rndInt = randomShort(1,1000);
        if ((hr = row.SetShort(L"RNDINT",rndInt)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }

        point->x = randomDouble(-180.0,180.0);
        point->y = randomDouble(-90.0,90.0);
        if ((hr = row.SetGeometry(pointGeom)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }

        if ((hr = table.Insert(row)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }
        written++;
    }
    
/*
 * .. Clear write lock
 */
bailout:
    if ((hr = table.FreeWriteLock()) != S_OK) {
        if (msg.empty()) ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
    }

    return msg;

} /* populateTable */
```

which was invoked from a driver loop in main:

```c
/*
 * .. Insert pseudo-random rows to FCs
 */
    elapsed();
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // Open table
        if ((hr = geodatabase.OpenTable(nameTable(i),tmpTable)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }
    // Insert to table
        msg = populateTable(tmpTable);
        if (!msg.empty()) goto bailout;
    // Close table
        if ((hr = geodatabase.CloseTable(tmpTable)) != S_OK) {
            ErrorInfo::GetErrorDescription(hr,msg);
            goto bailout;
        }
        ms_insert += elapsed();
    }
```

There are two main differences in our code:

1. I use `table.SetWriteLock()` to obtain a write lock for bulk insert,
   then free it with `table.FreeWriteLock()`
2. You use `geodatabase.CompactDatabase()`, which forces a rewrite of all the table data files and indexes.

I expect that you'll have a much faster API experience if you set/free the write lock, and a slightly faster experience if you skip the unnecessary Compact operation.

In general, it's usually wise to add timing code when experiencing performance issues, so you can be sure where the delay occurs.  This is the platform independent (Linux/Windows) timing function I used (which returns milliseconds since last invocation):

```c
#if defined(WIN32)
#   include <sys/types.h>
#   include <sys/timeb.h>
#else
#   include <sys/time.h>
#   include <unistd.h>
#endif

double  elapsed(void)
{
    double secs;
#if defined(WIN32)
static  struct timeb     start = {0,0};
    struct timeb     now;

    ftime(&now);

    secs = (double)(now.time - start.time) * 1000.0 +
        ((double)now.millitm - (double)start.millitm);
#else
static  struct timeval   start = {0,0};
    struct timeval   now;

    gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

    secs = (double)(now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0 +
        (((double)now.tv_usec - (double)start.tv_usec) * 0.001);
#endif
    start = now;

    return secs;

} /* elapsed */
```

I'd guess that adding the write lock will cut the insert time to under 20 seconds,
and that the Compact probably adds 10 seconds to execution.

Comment: adding explicit locks fixed the bulk of the performance problem, evrything else i'm ok with considering the time needed to read the shape files and write the values to disk. The execution time went down from 20 minutes to ~1-2